# REACT: Early return, Rendered fewer hooks than expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am working on a project that creates a chrome extension. I am trying to return an object and I want to update it when curTab changed. However, I am getting an error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. How can I fix that?

```
export const CategoryHandling = () => {
  const tabHosts = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.tabHosts)
  const curTab = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.currentTab)
  const ns3Cache = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.ns3Cache)

  const [ctgObject, setCategoryObject] = useState({
    ads: [],
    malware: [],
    tracking: [],
    family: [],
    adult: [],
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    setCategoryObject({
      ads: [],
      malware: [],
      tracking: [],
      family: [],
      adult: [],
    })
  }, [curTab])

  const hosts = curTab?.id ? tabHosts[curTab.id] : []
  hosts &&
    hosts.length !== 0 &&
    hosts.map((host) => {
      if (
        ns3Cache?.[host] &&
        ns3Cache?.[host].length !== 0 &&
        !ns3Cache[host].hasOwnProperty('isLoading')
      ) {
        ns3Cache[host].map((matchesItem) => {
          if (
            !ctgObject[matchesItem['list_category']].includes(
              matchesItem['hostname']
            )
          ) {
            ctgObject[matchesItem['list_category']].push(
              matchesItem['hostname']
            )
          }
        })
      }
    })
  return ctgObject
}
```

Comment: The code in the question won't cause the error you've described, you're consistently calling the same hooks on every render (which is good, that's what you should do). Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: But the answer to how to fix the error you've described is: Ensure you always call the same hooks in the same order on every render (don't skip hooks by returning early). As I said above, the code shown does that, but apparently you have code that doesn't do that, which is what you have to fix.

Answer (score 3):

This is caused because of calling hooks inside iterations or conditional blocks, the more common scenarios in which I've found this kind of error happening were like:

```
// Using useSelector inside a map function
const myList = someIds.map((id) => useSelector((state) => state.someSlice[id]));

// Calling useEffect inside if block
if(someCondition) {
    useEffect(() => {
        // doing some stuff
    }, []);
}
```

Look up for this kind of errors in your components.